# Call function in the same namespace fail + inheritance problem

Tags: c++, clang++

I got the following code:

```
//in file.h
namespace mynamespace{
     struct myStruct{
          // member variables of struct
     }
     int foo(myStruct &item);
     // Here someClass is a completely virtual class (not instantiable)
     // and someClass itself is implemented/declared as a template
     template<template <class T> class someClass> int helpFoo(myStruct &item);
}

// in file.cpp (I put the implementations in here)
int mynamespace::foo(myStruct &item){
     // where inheritedClass is a child of someClass and T is a self-implemented class
     return helpFoo<inheritedClass<T>>(item);
}
```

I have several problems with this code.

1.The compiler(clang++) throws an error saying:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'helpFoo'
```

and a note:

```
note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
  argument for template parameter 'someClass'
```

2. In helpFoo() function I need to instantiate an inheritedClass object, how can I do that?

I seldom work with clang++ compiler and nested templates+inheritance like this so it's super confusing to me. Any help is appreciated.

################# update #####################

I figure my problem 1 out. The line of return in foo() should be:

```
return helpFoo<inheritedClass>(item);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

that's because you already specified inheritedClass's template parameter T, which is just `class T`, template template parameters works only when you don't specify the template arguments for a certain class. so there are 2 solutions:

- use `template<class T>`  and pass `helpFoo<inheritedClass<T>>`
- use `template<template<class> class someClass, class T>` and pass it as `helpFoo<inheritedClass, T>`